# Connecting to a specific shell instance in a docker container?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, containers

Let's say I have a running docker container `my_container`. I start a new shell session with:

`docker exec -it my_container bash`

And then I start a process (a Python script for example), and exit the container with `cntrl-p` then `cntrl-q` to keep the script running in the background. If I do this a few different times with a few different scripts, how do I reconnect to a specific shell instance so I can see the std out of my scripts? If I use `docker attach my_container`, I'm always placed into the first shell instance I initiated when I did my `docker run` command.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to start [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) inside the first shell. And then start any other processes inside a new window.

Although it is theoretically possible to do so, `docker exec` still has many issues and it is always better to avoid it for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial mode, but may be it helps. Instead of "echo "..." substitude with your script names.

Run the container, then run your scripts directly with docker exec and redirect their output to different files.

```
docker exec -ti containerId /bin/bash -c 'echo "Hello script1" > /var/log/1.log'
docker exec -ti containerId /bin/bash -c 'echo "Hello script2" > /var/log/2.log'
```

Then you can look at the files by docker exec(uting) some other commands like cat, grep, tail or whatever you want:

```
docker exec -ti containerId /bin/tail -f /var/log/1.log
docker exec -ti containerId /bin/tail -f /var/log/2.log
```

Remind you could also use

```
docker logs containerId
```

to see the output redirect to /dev/stdout from commands running in the container, but, if I understood your need, in this case you would get the output from many scritps mixed in stdout.